# write Regex to find match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I never wrote any complex regular expression before, and what I need seems to be (at least) a bit complicated.

I need a Regex to find matches for the following:

```
"On Fri, Jan 16, 2015 at 4:39 PM"
```

Where `On` will always be there;

then 3 characters for week day;

`,` is always there;

space is always there;

then 3 characters for month name;

space is always there;

day of month (one or two numbers);

`,` is always there;

space is always there;

4 numbers for year;

space `at` space always there;

time (have to match `4:39` as well as `10:39`);

space and 2 caps letters for `AM` or `PM`.

Comment: What is your regexp so far ? What does not work with it ?

Comment: Are you saying you only want to capture `4:39` and `10:39` like @Avinash interpreted or are those just examples of a 1 digit hour and a 2 digit hour and you would like to match any hour/minute value?

Comment: @funkwurm those were just examples, you are right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
On\s+(?:Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun), (?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|June|July|Aug|Sept|Oct|Nov|Dec) \d{1,2}, \d{4} at \d{1,2}:\d{2} (?:AM|PM)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: this one works really like a charm! I've chosen this one, because it looks understandable even for such regex dummy as I am

Answer (score 4):

Here's a very simple and readable one:

```
/On \w{3}, \w{3} \d{1,2}, \d{4} at \d{1,2}:\d{2} [AP]M/
```

[See it on rubular](http://rubular.com/r/CxkKy6h4Y9)

Answer (score 3):

```
/On \w{3}, \w{3} \d{1,2}, \d{4} at \d{1,2}:\d{1,2} [A-Z]{2}/

# \w{3} for 3 charecters
# \d{1,2} for a or 2 digits
# \d{4} for 4 digits
# [A-Z]{2} for 2 capital leters
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below regex and it won't check for the month name or day name or date.

```
^On\s[A-Z][a-z]{2},\s[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}\sat\s(?:10|4):39\s[AP]M$
```

[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/yQcktbdo8t)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rubular](http://rubular.com) to construct and test Ruby Regular Expressions.

I have put together an Example: http://rubular.com/r/45RIiwheqs

Since it looks you try to parse dates, you should use [Date.strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime).

Answer (score 0):

/On [A-Za-z]{3}, [A-Za-z]{3} \d{1,2}, \d{4} at \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}/g

Comment: returns `unknown regexp option - g`, sorry

Comment: Try after omitting that, I have tested in perl, working fine. g stands for matching globally.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are describing the problem makes me thing that the format will always be preserved.

I would then in your case use the `Time.parse` function, passing the format string

```
format = "On %a, %b"On Fri, Jan 16, 2015 at 4:39 PM", format)
```

which is more readable than a regexp (in my opinion) and has the added value that it returns a `Time` object, which is easier to use than a regexp match, in case you need to perform other time-based calculations.

Another good thing is that if the string contains an invalid date (like "On Mon, Jan 59, 2015 at 37:99 GX" ) the `parse` function will raise an exception, so that validation is done for free for you.